# exclude i686 packages in yum.conf

Tags: centos, yum

I'm trying to exclude *.i686 packages from installing when I try to install the x86_64 version of libcrypto.so.10.

If I put any of the following (one at a time) into my `/etc/yum.conf` under `[main]`:

```
multilib_policy=best
exactarch=1
exclude=*.i386 *.i686
exclude=*.i?86
```

And I try to install the package it says that it isn't there:

```
sudo yum install libcrypto.so.10
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin, tsflags, versionlock
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No package libcrypto.so.10 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

However if I remove any of those settings it tries to install both `i686` and the `x86_64` version of `libcrypto.so.10`. I am using Centos version: `CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)`

How can I exclude `*.i686` packages in the `/etc/yum.conf` file?

Comment: Which version of CentOS is this?

Comment: It's centos 7.7.

Answer (score 2):

You couldn't install `libcrypto.so.10` by mentioned command. First you should locate which package contains this library by executing `yum provides libcrypto.so.10` and then install package.

Or you could directly install [required package](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/openssl-libs-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64.rpm.html).

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't address the question of how I exclude `*.i686` packages from being installed using `/etc/yum.conf`. I want to be able to do this for other packages as well, not just for `libcrypto.so.10`.

Answer (score 0):

The way to exclude packages with "i686" in their name is by adding the exclude directive to repository configuration files in `/etc/yum.repos.conf/`. For example, by adding:

```
exclude=*i686*
```

I would be careful with that because it doesn't really exclude package by architecture, only by their name.